# How to get all child pages of a parent page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

Example:

```
About
--- Menu 1
--- Menu 2
--- Menu 3
--- Menu 4
```

if i'm in about page... i have the sub pages.
but, if enter to Menu 1 all the pages disappear

What i need is all the time see the parent pages

Currently I have this code

```
<? if (is_page()) {
    $g_page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
    wp_list_pages("depth=4&title_li=&child_of=".$g_page_id."&sort_column=menu_order");
   }
?>
```

Thanks!

**Resolved**

i use this and work fine!

```php
<?php
if ( is_page() ) :
    if( $post->post_parent ) :
        $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0' );
    else;
        $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
    endif;
    if ($children) : ?>
        <div class="title">
            <?php
            $parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
            echo $parent_title;
            ?>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: You should try to search next time. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190427/how-to-get-all-child-pages-of-a-page-by-the-parent-page-title-in-wordpress

Comment: This code does not work for me, i got a error.

Answer (score 15):

Here you go. A bit late for the author, but people will come here for an answer still ;-)

```
<?php 
// determine parent of current page
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors) - 1];
} else {
    $parent = $post->ID;
}

$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");

if ($children) {
?>

    <ul class="subnav">
        <?php 
            // current child will have class 'current_page_item'
            echo $children; 
        ?>
    </ul>

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: You already have parent ID in `$post->post_parent` so why use `get_post_ancestors` to get parent?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to handle this is with `get_children()`. It pretty much does what you would expect. It returns the child pages of a parent page.

`get_children()` is basicly a wrapper for the `WP_Query` class.

You can use it like this...

```php
$child_args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // The parent id.
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$children = get_children( $child_args );
```

If you want to return the children of the current post, you can pass in `$post->ID` as the `'post_parent'`. Otherwise, use any ID you want.

[Documentation for `get_children()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/)

[Documentation for `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Fetch all child pages of a parent page*/    
$pages = get_pages(
         array (
         'parent'  => '-1',
         'child_of' => 'parent_id', /* Return child of child for current page id */
         'post_type  => 'page',
         'post_status'  => 'publish',
          );
         $ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
/* Return page IDs in array format */
/* You can retrieve "post_title", "guid", "post_name" instead of "ID" */

/* Fetch only one level child pages of a parent page */    
         $pages = get_pages(
         array (
                  'parent'  => 'parent_id', 
                  'post_type  => 'page', 
                  'post_status'  => 'publish',
                );
                
         $ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
 /* Return page IDs in array format */
 /* You can retrieve "post_title", "guid", "post_name" instead of "ID"
```